# Disable access to Location Service API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can access to the Location Service API be disabled?

I did receive a letter from the Microsoft Development Center which contains this tip:

> Your app must provide in-app settings that allow the user to enable
>   and disable your app's access to and use of location from the Location
>   Service API.

Can anyone provide further assistance on how I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Paste this code right after `InitializeComponent();` in MainPage.xaml. You will have to add reference to IsolatedStorage by this line `using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;`.

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("LocationConsent"))
{
    return;
}
else
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Allow this app to access your location?", "Location", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

    if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
       IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = true;
    }
    else
    {
       IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = false;
    }
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
}
```

Also create a **Settings.xaml** page with a **ToggleSwitch** which has the following code:

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("LocationConsent"))
{
    if ((bool)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] == true)
    {
       locationSwitch.IsChecked = true;
    }
    else
    {
       locationSwitch.IsChecked = false;
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Allow this app to access your location?", "Location", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

    if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
       IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = true;
    }
    else
    {
       IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = false;
    }
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
}

private void locationSwitch_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("LocationConsent"))
    {
       IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = true;
       IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
    }
}

private void locationSwitch_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("LocationConsent"))
   {
      IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = false;
      IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
   }
}
```

And on the page that you use Location / GPS data include the following code:

```
if ((bool)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] == true)
{
     //Do Something
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("Please enable location services to use this feature. You can turn it on from Settings.");
}
```

This will surely help. I use the same. Do upvote and mark as answer if this helps you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your app use location services and you need to have the ability to disable it OR are you asking in general?

If it's the first then just stop collecting data and disable it in your app. If it's the second then go into the WPmanifest and uncheck it